# Can you download a version of blender and still have access to the previous version

Tags: blend-files, eevee-render-engine

I am considering downloading the blender 2.8 beta but I had a question first. One, can you still access blender 2.79 with the beta downloaded, and if so how? I don't want to download it, have it crash a bunch and not be able to go back to 2.79.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, if you create a project in Blender 2.8 you can't open it with the 2.79 version. But you can open 2.79 projects with the 2.8 beta version, but if you save it using the 2.8 you won't be able to open it again with the 2.79.

When you download the 2.8 beta version, it isn't a setup (because is beta) so you have a portable file. That means that the desktop shortcut will be for the 2.79 and you have to create a new one for the 2.8 looking for the exe, so you could have both versions (actually I have the 2.79 shortcut next to the 2.8, both avaliable).

Comment: Thanks, that helps, but a big thing I was wondering is if once you download 2.8, how would you open 2.79, because when I open blender it automatically pulls up my latest version, and I'm worried I won't be able to open 2.79

Comment: Ahhhh I misundestand it, I'll update my answer.